# Simple form hidden association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

This is weird behavior.

I have this as part of a form:

```
<%= f.association :blog, collection: current_user.blogs, selected: @blog %>
```

**This works.** However, as soon as I add this extra attribute:

```
<%= f.association :blog, collection: current_user.blogs, selected: @blog, as: :hidden %>
```

I get a validation error saying that my model needs a blog to be associated with it. It seems that adding `as: :hidden` to it makes it lose the value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not need to be select, because it's hidden field. I think the following code will solve the problem:

```
<%= f.input :blog_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: @blog.id } %>
```